# Involutions on Hopf algebra crossed products

Tags: reference-request, hopf-algebras

I am interested in a [(cocycle) crossed product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crossed+product+algebra) of a Hopf algebra $H$ with a (twisted) $H$-module algebra $A$, often denoted $H\#_\sigma A$, where $\sigma$ is the associated cocycle.  This construction was introduced by, I think, [Doi and Takeuchi](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927878608823337) and [Blattner, Cohen and Montgomery](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1986-298-02/S0002-9947-1986-0860387-X/home.html); and also studied by Majid in the context when $A$ is also Hopf, and $H\#_\sigma A$ is a bialgebra (so a bicrossed product).

I am interested in the case when $H$ is a Hopf $*$-algebra and $A$ is a $*$-algebra, and what conditions we might place on $\sigma$ to obtain a "natural" $*$-algebra structure on $H\#_\sigma A$.  This problem is briefly considered by [Andruskiewitsch](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/notes-on-extensions-of-hopf-algebras/065D559B6D9912019316B69EAD73D2EF); see Section 3.2.

> Are there other sources which consider $H\#_\sigma A$ with a $*$-structure; what were the first papers to do this?

When considering $*$-structures, it is of course natural to start to look at $C^*$-algebras and von Neumann algebras, and analogues of cocycle crossed products have been considered for e.g. Kac algebras and locally compact quantum groups.  I am here interested only in the purely algebraic framework.